# Run different ASP.NET Core webapps under same domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express, kestrel

I'm trying to create a container (parent) web app loading other web applications inside its body. 
Each web app is an ASP.Net Core project, using its own Kestrel web server. With old ASP.Net, I would use virtual directories to have them under same the same site, avoiding the concern to handle cross domain CORS, but I can't find a way to do it with asp.net core modules.

**Container** (localhost)

- App1 (localhost/App1)
- App2 (localhost/App2)
- App3 (localhost/App3)

Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with Kestrel on it's own, and in fact, Kestrel is not yet supported to be run as an internet facing server. You could do it with the IIS integration though.

Comment: Any hint or example on how to do it on a development environment?

Comment: Use IIS locally to try it, it should be fairly simple though I've never had to do this.

Comment: Could you solve this? I have the exact same scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You need change default app name in Web.config, each new application has a different name: `<add name="herenewapp" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />`